# seperate string number ranges in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which looks like this

```
Type    range
Mike    10..13|7|8|
Ni      3..4
NANA    2|1|6
```

and desired output should look like this

```
Type    range
Mike    10
Mike    11
Mike    12
Mike    13
Mike    7
Mike    8
Nico    3
Nico    4
NANA    2
NANA    1
NANA    6
```

so, Totaling column presenet the multiple values per Type. range values are presnted with two `number` seperated by two `..` and one value (with no range) is presented between two `| |`

Comment: For Mike, the range in your first df is `10..15` but in your desired output it only goes to 13. Why? Also, are your ranges meant to be exclusive or inclusive (so including the last number in the range or not)?

Comment: correcyed the range, and its inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your ranges are inclusive, which I assume because your '3..4' translates to a row with 3 and a row with 4, and assuming that you forgot to put Mike 14 and Mike 15 in your example output, I found the following solution:

```
import pandas as pd

def parse_str(s):
    numbers = []
    for v in s.rstrip('|').split('|'):
        if v.isdigit():
            numbers.append(int(v))
        else:
            start, end = v.split('..')
            numbers.extend(list(range(int(start), int(end)+1)))
    return pd.Series(numbers)

df.index = df['Type']
dfnew = df['range'].apply(parse_str).stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0: 'range'})
```

We write a function that parses the string, which means splitting the string by `|` and converting the numbers to integers if the string is already a number. Otherwise, it's a range so we split again by `..` and create a list with all the numbers in the range. In the end, we return a pd.Series containing all the numbers from the string.

Then, we apply that function to the column with `df['range'].apply` and stack the result. To assure we still keep the names, we have to first set it as the index of the dataframe.

Comment: it gives me an error KeyError: 'Type' on  `df.index = df['Type']`

Comment: I fixed the error but now it gives me an `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.414900'`

Comment: So you are also using floats not only ints? If that is the case, how are the ranges supposed to work if there are floats involved? You could just replace all `int()` with `float()` in my code above, but then the ranges won't work.

Comment: okay, I just notcied that in some cases there are three `...` instead of two `..`

Comment: since then trying to add the second  delimiter 3 dot but keep getting error. any idea how can I solve it?

Comment: Before you run my code above, you can simply clean up the column of any occurences of three dots by replacing them with two dots. `df['range'] = df['range'].str.replace('...', '..')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```py
# split by '|' and explode
df = df.assign(range=df['range'].str.split('|')).explode('range')

# get the range(i, j) if the string has '..'
df['range'] = df['range'].apply(lambda r: range(int(r.split('..')[0]), int(r.split('..')[1])) if (len(r.split('..')) == 2) else r)

# explode
df = df.explode('range')
df

    Type    range
0   Mike       10
0   Mike       11
0   Mike       12
0   Mike       13
0   Mike       14
0   Mike        7
0   Mike        8
1     Ni        3
2   NANA        2
2   NANA        1
2   NANA        6
```

Comment: give me an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '613300|623510|644001|644003'`